# $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1-\cosh(x/k)$ converges for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

How can I show that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1-\cosh\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)$$ converges for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Root and ratio tests are inconclusive. Tried something with the Taylor series and this came out: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1-\cosh\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\cosh(x)}{x^2-1}$$

Also tried using the convexity of $\cosh$ to find some upper bound but no results.

Comment: What did you do with the Taylor series? The right argument with the Taylor series yields the convergence, even the uniform convergence on all bounded intervals.

Comment: I think you mean $\sum_{k=\color{red}{1}}^\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p,q \in \mathbb R$, you have
$$\cosh p - \cosh q = 2  \sinh \left( \frac{p+q}{2}\right) \sinh \left( \frac{p-q}{2}\right)$$ hence for $x \in \mathbb R$ and $k \in \mathbb  N$
$$1- \cosh x/k = -2 \sinh^2 \left( \frac{x}{2k} \right)$$

You can then conclude as you have series with positive terms and
$$\sinh^2 \left( \frac{x}{2k} \right) \sim \frac{x^2}{4k^2}$$ for $k \to \infty$ and $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}$ converges.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $1-\cosh(x/k)=2\sinh^2(x/2k)$?

Comment: @Xena Yes, you're right. Thanks.